# symfony php multiplying result from query

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am new to symfony and I am trying to build an array that should look like this:

> ['10' => 100, '100' => 40, '200' => 10, 'reis' => 1]

The data comes from my database obviously, so here is my query:

```
$chances = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM prices");
```

This results an array with objects:

```
[{"id":"1","price":"10","amount":"1000","chance":"0,5"},
{"id":"2","price":"100","amount":"100","chance":"0,2"},
{"id":"3","price":"200","amount":"10","chance":"0,05"},
{"id":"4","price":"reis","amount":"1","chance":"0,005"},
{"id":"5","price":"noprice","amount":"0","chance":"0,245"}]
```

Now I need to multiply the chance by 200 and fill my array I do this like so:

```
foreach ($chances as $chance){
  $p = $chance['price'];
  $c = (200 * $chance['chance']);
  $chancesArr[] = array($p => $c);
}
```

But for some reason I get always 0 as a result

Anyone knows why the multiply doesnt work?

And I have another little problem the $chancesArr is a multidimensional array but it should be 1 array with keys as the $p and values are the $c

My result:

> [{"10":0},{"100":0},{"200":0},{"reis":0}]

My goal:

> ['10' => 100, '100' => 40, '200' => 10, 'reis' => 1]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is because of comma in number, try to replace comma by point

```
$chances = '[{"id":"1","price":"10","amount":"1000","chance":"0,5"},
{"id":"2","price":"100","amount":"100","chance":"0,2"},
{"id":"3","price":"200","amount":"10","chance":"0,05"},
{"id":"4","price":"reis","amount":"1","chance":"0,005"},
{"id":"5","price":"noprice","amount":"0","chance":"0,245"}]';

$chances = json_decode($chances, true);

foreach ($chances as $chance){
    $p = $chance['price'];
    $c = 200 * str_replace(',', '.', $chance['chance']);
    $chancesArr[$p] = $c;
}

echo json_encode($chancesArr);
```

output: `{"10":100,"100":40,"200":10,"reis":1,"noprice":49}`

Comment: You are right sir! Do you have any idea how I can make 1 array if my result instead of an array with objects?

Comment: Hey I understand what you're doing but for some reason I get back 0 1 2 reis instead of 10 100 200 reis

Comment: That is strange, I've placed full code, everything is fine on my server

Comment: Im very sorry I am just a bit stupid and did something wrong! My apologies